# Is it possible to set the Analytics ID in gatsby-node.js?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, gatsby, analytics

I'm using Gatsby to create a static page. The contents are comming from a CMS with rest-API.

Now I would like to add Google-Analyitcs, and also save the trackingId in the CMS.
But when I'm using the `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`, I have to set the trackingId in the `gatsby-config.js`.

Is there any way, to fetch the data in `gatsby-node.js` and then set/change the trackingId for the plugin?

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

In the end, `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` or any similar plugin what it's doing is to [customize the `html.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/) to add a script with the ID in it. This is created as a boilerplate/template for the content coming from your data sources (in your `gatsby-node.js`) while your site is being built, as you can see in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/):

> Gatsby gives plugins and site builders many APIs for building your
> site. Code in the file `gatsby-node.js` is run once in the process of
> **building** your site. You can use its APIs to create pages dynamically,
> add data into GraphQL, or respond to events during the **build**
> **lifecycle**.
>
> Every Gatsby Node API gets passed a set of helper functions. These let
> you access several methods like reporting, or perform actions like
> creating new pages.

However, what you can do, is to set the tracking ID manually via React [`Helmet`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/) based on the content of your CMS, this would be simpler to achieve. In your `createPage` function you can do:

```
createPage({
  path: `/somePath/${node.id}`,
  component: yourComponent,
  context: {
    trackingId: node.trackingId,
  },
})
```

The `trackingId` stands for your analytics tracking ID and will be available under `props.pageContext.trackingId` in your front-end view.